# How to pass an attribute to a controller converter in Silex?

Tags: php, symfony, controller, silex

As of here: http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/usage.html#route-variable-converters
I want to define the converter as service to use Doctrine ORM.

If I use:

```
$app['converter.user'] = function ($user, Request $request) use ($em){
     print($request->attributes->get('user'));
     return new UserConverter($em);
};

$app->get('/user/{user}', function (Silex\Application $app, Request $request, $user) {
      return $app->json($user);
})
->convert('user', 'converter.user:convert');
```

The 'user' attribute is not available in service and I get the error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null`

But if instead of a service I use a variable like below then the attribute 'user' works fine! what wrong I did above? I need to pass the value of 'user' attribute to pass to `convert()` method of `UserConverter()` class, how can I do so from the service above?

```
$user = function ($user, Request $request) use ($em){
        print($request->attributes->get('user'));
        return new UserConverter($em);
};
$app->get('/user/{user}', function (Silex\Application $app, Request $request, $user) {
      return $app->json($user);
})
->convert('user', $user);
```

Answer (score 0):

please debug those functions(print out $user).
Then you will see that in the second part you have doubled name variable $user that makes the difference.

That in the first example you use the DI container, so you should pass the request into it.